# asp.net mvc dropdown view bag

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a dropdown in `asp.net` MVC which contains paid accounts, trial accounts and all accounts, but when I click on any one of these options, it should display accounts related to that specific category in the data table  but there is no response when I click on any of these options from the drop-down, I mean those accounts are not getting listed.
[image]

Comment: How on earth can anyone help if you do not show your code?

Answer (score 0):

possible reasons for your problem

1. Drop down is not populated with proper integer values
2. On select of drop down item , appropriate item value is not used to fetch accounts